# Moving Windows 10 to Linux VMware on same hardware

Tags: linux, windows-10, vmware, windows-activation

I have a local installation of Windows 10, activated and bound to hardware.

Does anybody know if it is possible to transfer this activation into a virtual machine on the same computer, only with Linux installed as the main OS and Win 10 in VMware Workstation?

Comment: I don't know but would guess not - because virtual pc will have different hardware(virtual models); have to read MS EULA to understand if it is fine to have win10 as virtual on same machine where it was physical or just call MS support and ask, because ofc if you bought lic - they may allow this even its not in eula.

Comment: Since the hardware will change quite a bit, my guess is that it won't stay activated. Perhaps it is possible to reactivate via a phone call, but I've never done it with Windows 10, so I'm not sure.